# How do you clear user inputs?

Tags: python, while-loop

So Im making the trade system on Monopoly using numbers. For example, if I want to add something, I input the number 1, if I want to remove something, I input the number 2, etc. My problem is, if I exit out the while loop, basically the code "break", that previous input to break also activates the main menu's if commands as well. If your confused what I am trying to say, I don't know if I'm allowed to post links on this website, but the link is:
https://repl.it/@BrentTersol/Monopoly-Official

```py
if Action == 2 :
      while True:
        replit.clear()
        print("What would you like to give?\n1: Add\n2: Remove\n3: Clear\n4: Offer Trade\n5: Cancel\n6: Switch")
        Action = int(input(">>> "))
        if Action == 1:
          while True:
            replit.clear()
            print("What would you like to add?\n1: Money\n2: Property\n3: Jail Free Card\n4: Back")
            Action = int(input(">>> "))
            if Action == 1:
              if Turn == 1:
                while True:
                  replit.clear()
                  print("How much money do you want to give for the trade?\nMoney:",str(Player1Money))
                  Action = int(input(">>> "))
                  if Action >= 0 and Action <= (Player1Money):
                    TMoney1 = (Action)
                    print("You added $"+str(TMoney1),"to the trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                  else:
                    print("You do not have enough money")
                    break
              if Turn == 2:
                while True:
                  replit.clear()
                  print("How much money do you want to give for the trade?\nMoney:",str(Player2Money))
                  Action = int(input(">>> "))
                  if Action >= 0 and Action <= (Player2Money):
                    TMoney2 = (Action)
                    print("You added $"+str(TMoney2),"to the trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                  if Action == "back":
                    break
                  else:
                    print("You do not have enough money")
                    break
            if Action == 2:
              while True:
                replit.clear()
                if Turn == 1:
                  print(Inventory1)
                if Turn == 2:
                  print(Inventory2)
                print("What property do you want to give?")
                Action = int(input(">>> "))
                if Turn == 1:
                  if (Action) in (Inventory1):
                    TProperty1.append((Action))
                    print("Added",(Action),"to the trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                  else:
                    print("Item not found in your properties")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                if Turn == 2:
                  if (Action) in (Inventory2):
                    TProperty2 = (Action)
                    print("Added",(Action),"to the trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                  else:
                    print("Item not found in your properties")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
            if Action == 3:
              if Turn == 1:
                if JailCard1 == 1:
                  TCard1 = 1
                  print("Added Jail Free Card to the trade.")
                  time.sleep(2)
                else:
                  print("You do not own a Jail Free Card")
                  time.sleep(2)
              if Turn == 2:
                if JailCard2 == 1:
                  TCard1 = 1
                  print("Added Jail Free Card to the trade.")
                  time.sleep(2)
                else:
                  print("You do not own a Jail Free Card")
                  time.sleep(2)
            if Action == 4:
              break
        if Action == 2:
          while True:
            replit.clear()
            print("What would you like to remove?\n1: Money\n2: Property\n3: Jail Free Card\n4: Back")
            Action = int(input(">>> "))
            if Action == 1:
              while True:
                replit.clear()
                if Turn == 1:
                  if TMoney1 == 0:
                    print("There wasn't any money to remove")
                    time.sleep(2)
                  else:
                    TMoney1 = 0
                    print("Removed Cash from offer")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
            if Action == 2:
              while True:
                replit.clear()
                print(TProperty1)
                print("What property would you like to remove")
                Action = input(">>> ")
                Action = Action.lower()
                if Turn == 1:
                  if Action == "back":
                    break
                  if (Action) in (TProperty1):
                    TProperty1.remove((Action))
                    print("Removed",(TProperty1),"from trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
                  else:
                    print("That item did not exist")
                    time.sleep(2)
                if Turn == 2:
                  if (Action) in (TProperty2):
                    TProperty2.remove((Action))
                    print("Removed",(TProperty2),"from trade")
                    time.sleep(2)
                  else:
                    print("That item did not exist")
                    time.sleep(2)
            if Action == 3:
              if Turn == 1:
                if JailCard1 == 1:
                  print("Removed Jail Free Card from trade")
                  TCard1 = 0
                  break
                else:
                  print("Card does not exist in trade")
              if Turn == 2:
                if JailCard2 == 1:
                  print("Removed Jail Free Card from trade")
                  TCard2 = 0
                  break
                else:
                  print("Card does not exist in trade")
            if Action == 4:
              break
        if Action == 3:
          TMoney1 = 0
          TMoney2 = 0
          TProperty1.clear()
          TProperty2.clear()
          TCard1 = 0
          TCard2 = 0
        if Action == 4:
          if Turn == 1:
            while True:
              print("This is what",(Name1),"offers:\n--------------------")
              time.sleep(2)
              print("You get:\nMoney:",(TMoney1),"\nProperty:",(TProperty1),"\nGet out of Jail Free Card:",(TCard1),"\n")
              time.sleep(2)
              print("You give",(Name1)+":\nMoney:",(TMoney2),"\nProperty:",(TProperty2),"\nGet out of Jail Free Card:",(TCard2),"\n")
              time.sleep(2)
              print("Do you accept this Offer? (Y/N):")
              Action = input(">>> ")
              Action = Action.lower()
              if Action == "y":
                print("This is beyond what I can do at this point. Very sorry you took a long time not knowing that it wouldnt work. But this will soon be fixed as soon as I know how to do this")
                time.sleep(5)
              else:
                print("Trade has been rejected")
                time.sleep(2)
                break
        if Action == 5:
          if Turn == 1:
            Turn = 2
          else:
            Turn = 1
        if Action == 6:
          print("This is beyond what I can do. Please wait until I learn how to do this. Thank you.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you start a new python file and create a simple example that illustrates the same problem as your full program. I also suggest that you learn about functions and classes. These tools can help you organize your code as it continues to become more complex.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Please see [A Wall of Code isn't Helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: Btw, try to split code into functions, cause few months later you'd rather die than find where to apply needed edits...

Comment: This slab of code utterly terrifies me. The code in the link is only worse. I think you should take some time to learn about lists and functions. They will make this task *a lot* easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a single `While True` loop and that will reset the user input each loop (so long as you overwrite it *inside* the loop)! I would also advise you recreate your code into functions instead of several nested logic statements. An example of code that gets user input each loop (in the terms of your question **clears user input**):

```
while True:
    big_prompt = """What would you like to do?
    1) say hi
    2) say bye
    3) pay taxes
    4) ???
    5) profit
    6) Exit D:"""
    action = input(big_prompt) # reset user input each loop
    if action not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]:
        print("Sorry I didn't understand that")
        continue # get a new user input
    # at this point we know user input fits our criteria
    if action == "1":
        print("Hi!")
    elif action == "2":
        print("Bye!")
    # ... you should be putting function calls in these for more complex tasks
    elif action == "6":
        break # this only exits one loop, I think you are trying to use it to
```

With sample output:

```
What would you like to do?
    1) say hi
    2) say bye
    3) pay taxes
    4) ???
    5) profit
    6) Exit D:
    >>>1
Hi!
What would you like to do?
    1) say hi
    2) say bye
    3) pay taxes
    4) ???
    5) profit
    6) Exit D:
    >>>6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It also might be a good idea to review *The Zen of Python* by opening an interactive terminal and running `import this`:

```
>>>import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Where of special note we find a couple things that apply here:

> Flat is better than nested.
>
> Readability counts.

Maintaining a single while loop greatly helps both of these. At one point in your code you get trapped inside **3** `while True:` loops and then try to break multiple with a single `break`, but will always stay trapped at least 2 levels deep...